# ERROR 400-->wcf bad request from clientside

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, wcf

I'm new to WCF.I'm trying to call WCF from my aspx page to post xml and return json.My service works well but I'm getting an error of "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request".Maybe WCF's config file gives such a error response to me.I tried lot but confusion only comes me..help me in code guys please..
And my client side code is

```
string SampleXml = @"<parent>" +
               "<child>" +
                  "<username>username</username>" +
                    "<password>password</password>" +
                   "</child>" +
                "</parent>";
        //ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        string postData = SampleXml.ToString();
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData); 
        string url = "http://localhost:52573/Service1.svc/postjson/";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "applicatoin/xml;charset=utf-8";
        //request.Accept = "application/json";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;
        String test = String.Empty;
        Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        newStream.Close();
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            test = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
        }
        Response.Write(test);
```

And WCF's Web.config file code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>
<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
<authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
</authorization>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <identity impersonate="false" />
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="JsonandXmlService.Service1"    behaviorConfiguration="myServiceBehavior">
 <!--http://localhost:52573/Service1.svc/postjson/-->
    <endpoint name="myServiceBehavior" address="" binding="webHttpBinding"  contract="JsonandXmlService.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="webHttp">
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint name="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" behaviorConfiguration="webHttp" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="myServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior>
      <!--<!â€“ To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
             set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint 
             above before deployment â€“>-->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <!--<!â€“ To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
             set the value below to true. Set to false before deployment 
             to avoid disclosing exception information â€“>-->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webHttp">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<protocolMapping>
    <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="https" />

</protocolMapping>    
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false" />

<directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

And my service file is here

```
       public string postjson(string streamdata)
       {
        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(streamdata);          
       }
```

And interface is

```
 [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "postjson",Method="POST",RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    string postjson(string streamdata);
```

Comment: <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="http" /> How about this?
And when you open url where your web service resides, does it show you description of the webservice?

Comment: Thanks for replying buddy but it is not working yet too...sorry

Comment: request.ContentType = "applicatoin/xml;charset=utf-8";   "application" is spelled wrong... whether that is your problem or not, I'm not sure.  To clarify... do you mean that the server-side service works correctly and is tested?

Comment: Thanks Nathan..but still 400 is populating here...

Comment: That is not enough information. Can you add your WCF service implementation to the question details, especially the postJson method?

Comment: ya http://stackoverflow.com/users/2046805/the-zencoder i've added my wcf implementation now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time of struggle output came here..I didn't change any code in web.config of WCF.Here my Client side codes is

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // Restful service URL
        string url = "http://localhost:52573/Service1.svc/postjson";
        // declare ascii encoding
        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        string strResult = string.Empty;
        // sample xml sent to Service & this data is sent in POST
        string SampleXml = @"<parent>" +
               "<child>" +
                  "<username>username</username>" +
                    "<password>password</password>" +
                   "</child>" +
                "</parent>";
        string postData = SampleXml.ToString();
        // convert xmlstring to byte using ascii encoding
        byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
        // declare httpwebrequet wrt url defined above
        HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        // set method as post
        webrequest.Method = "POST";
        // set content type
        //webrequest.Accept = "application/xml;q=0.8";
        //webrequest.ContentType = "application/xml;charset=utf-8";
        webrequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        // set content length
        webrequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
        // get stream data out of webrequest object
        Stream newStream = webrequest.GetRequestStream();
        newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        newStream.Close();
        // declare & read response from service
        HttpWebResponse webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)webrequest.GetResponse();

        // set utf8 encoding
        Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
        // read response stream from response object
        StreamReader loResponseStream =
            new StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream(), enc);
        // read string from stream data
        strResult = loResponseStream.ReadToEnd();
        // close the stream object
        loResponseStream.Close();
        // close the response object
        webresponse.Close();
        // below steps remove unwanted data from response string
        Response.Write(strResult);

    }
```

And my service implementation code is

```
     public string postjson(Stream streamdata)
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(streamdata);
        string xmlString = reader.ReadToEnd();
        string returnValue = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(xmlString);
        return returnValue.ToString();
    }
```

This is what i did guys...And I cleared recent files too...